# Linguistic function of commas in English

Tags: punctuation

To me, it seems that the information about the usage of commas in English is for the most part prescriptive. Very few sources actually *explain*; indeed, I have yet to see any such source.

If you go online and research 'comma uses', you will find lists of 'rules' regarding the usage of commas. To name a few of these rules:

> Use commas to separate independent clauses joined by coordinating conjunctions (FANBOYS). E.g. 'Cars will turn here, and coaches will go straight on'
>
> Use commas after introductory phrases or clauses. E.g. "Once you have done your task, you must come to see me immediately".
>
> Use commas before directly addressing someone. E.g. "If I may interrupt, Your Majesty".
>
> etc.

One thing that all of these 'rules' have in common is that the authorities who prescribe them - if authorities they may be called - offer very little evidence to support their claims - indeed, often no evidence at all. If these authorities *did* offer evidence, then the basis for their rules would most likely be found in the way that the English language is actually written - represented on paper or by some other medium - by its speakers. Yet there is no such evidence in written English. Consider the below sentences, for instance.

> Hi John, how are you doing?
>
> If he does it then he's a fool.
>
> She must either go back to bed or get up.

Each of sentences violates one of the so-called rules regarding the usage of commas in English: the first sentence violates the rule that one must use a comma before a word in the vocative case; the second, that one must use a comma after an introductory clause; the third, that one must use a comma to separate independent clauses. Yet only the most tyrannical of linguistic prescriptivists would regard the above sentences as ungrammatical; most people (even many established writers) would see nothing wrong with these sentences.

It may therefore be seen that, in many cases, whether or not a comma is included is a matter of personal preference. There are exceptions, of course, amongst which is the case in which the absence of a comma leads to ambiguity. However, in my experience, many native English speakers neglect this, too, as they do with so many of the other rules. For instance, this sentence

> He didn't play golf because he was ill.

is ambiguous, and yet many English speakers would write the sentence without the comma but *with* the intention of conveying the meaning of the version containing the comma:

> He didn't play golf, because he was ill.

That commas are so often optional begs the question of why these rules still exist. Do commas have any syntactic or semantic function in English, or are they optional punctuation marks that prosodically set a constituent apart from the main clause? Does their prosodic 'separation' (for want of a better word) serve a linguistic purpose? To me, this sentence:

> If he does it, then he's a fool

is exactly the same as this sentence:

> If he does it then he's a fool

in all aspects but this one: after the *if* clause in the first sentence, there is a slight pause, a pause which serves no linguistic purpose.

If commas do indeed have a syntactic function, then how can one account for their decline? And if commas don't have any syntactic function in modern English, then did they use to? Did commas have syntactic functions in older versions of English? Were commas once obligatory?

---

TL;DR: In English, do commas play any role in marking the syntax or semantics of a sentence, and if not, did they have syntactic/semantic/other linguistic functions in older versions of English.

As a supplementary extension of this question, I would be interested to know if the comma (or punctuation in general) is facing a similar decline in other languages. If so, are there any explanations for this phenomenon? (I'm not sure if asking 'supplementary questions' is against the policy of this StackExchange. It probably is, and I won't be surprised if I am chided for asking a supplementary question. Nevertheless, I feel that it is suitable to ask it here.)

Thank you.

Comment: Commas are used differently in different writing systems. In German, for instance, they're strictly controlled by syntax. This is not true in English. The problem with the comma is that it's actually present in speech -- it marks an intonation contour, though some will say it's a pause because they don't know phonetics. That means that it can represent the contour to the reader, if they are the kind of reader who **hears** what they're reading, and not everybody does. At least in in English, which has only slightly more phonetic consistency than Chinese characters do.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because neither writing conventions nor the degree of how closely people usually follow them are in the scope of linguistics.

Comment: @YellowSky Mm, I think writing systems in general are linguistic enough to be worth talking about here. But I agree that asking about the rules of a particular writing system is not.

Comment: You may find these links useful, http://www.englishproject.org/resources/english-project%E2%80%99s-history-english-punctuation and http://www.viviancook.uk/Punctuation/PunctFigs.htm

Comment: And of course there’s David Crystal’s book, *Making a point: The Pernickety Story of English Punctuation*  https://profilebooks.com/work/making-a-point/

Comment: @jlawler. Right. If I may ask, does an intonation contour serve a semantic purpose?

Comment: An intonation contour does indeed serve a semantic purpose; but general rules for describing that purpose are hard to come by.

Comment: @Eric Well, yes. Compare:"I want a man who knows what love
is all about. You are generous, kind.
thoughtful. People who are not like
you admit to being useless and
inferior. You have ruined me for
other men. I yearn for you. I have no
feelings whatsoever when we're
apart. I can be forever happy
will
you let me be yours?" **versus**  ... (cont)

Comment: @Eric "I want a man who knows what love
is. All about you are generous, kind,
thoughtful people, who are not like
you. Admit to being useless and
inferior. You have ruined me. For
other men, I yearn. For you, I have
no feelings whatsoever. When we're
apart, I can be forever happy. Will
you let me be?" <--- The difference between those in speech is just intonation contours and where and when one tune ends and the next begins.

Comment: @Araucaria-him. Thank you for your response. However, what about more subtle intonation contours? For instance, the examples that I give: "If he does it, then he's a fool" and "If he does it then he's a fool". The former sentence contains a comma after the *if* clause; in the latter there is no such comma. What purpose does the intonation contour marked by the comma serve here, if any at all? I suspect that if there is a purpose, then it must be subtle. What do you think?

Comment: Also: I have heard that commas can often indicate a more loose connection between constituents. This is one of the justifications that I hear for the use of the serial comma. Let me illustrated. (1/...)

Comment: Consider, for instance, the two sentences "He is a kind, polite and respectful man" and "He is a kind, polite, and respectful man". Prescriptivists who think that a serial comma is here obligatory justify their thinking by claiming that the adjective 'respectful' is not more connected with 'man' than either 'kind' or 'polite'; the adjectives should all be connected in the same way.  While it is true that the serial comma is no longer obligatory here, I can understand why a prescriptivist might argue it is. (2/3)

Comment: Is it true, then, that commas can indicate a more loose connection between constituents? To use my examples, is the protasis more closely connected to the apodosis in the light version ('If he does it then he's a fool') than it is in the heavy version ('If he does it, then he's a fool')? And if it is, does this have any semantic implication? Are there any subtle differences in meaning between the light version (without the comma; more closely connected) and the heavy version (with the comma; more loosely connected). I apologise if my wording is not as clear as it could be.

Comment: Commas, like other punctuation, and like all other parts of the English writing system, and all parts of the actual language it attempts to represent, are used for many purposes. They barely convey anything of the actual language in action, which is **aural**, not written. All we can get from writing is an internal interpretation of what we think the author intended, including their intentions and possible deep feelings. The author can try for subtle shadings, but so can the reader. Good luck to both of them.

Comment: "In English, do commas play any role in marking the syntax or semantics of a sentence, and if not, did they have syntactic/semantic/other linguistic functions in older versions of English." surely the answer here is no, but the prosody they attempt to mark does. The question of how that prosody plays a role is far too open ended to be a single question though